# Wire.read() returns only 7-bit bytes

Tags: arduino

I'm a newbie to both Arduino programming and I2C in general. I'm using an Arduino Micro to extract data from the capacitance sensor AD7150.

Now in trying to answer my question myself, I've seen the basic setup of the Wire I2C communication a lot, and I feel like I have it down. But for some reason, Wire.read() only ever returns 7-bit bytes to me when it should be 8 bits from all that I see and understand. Another problem is that even if I read out a register that should be stable, i.e. the Chip ID register, the output "wobbles" over time. Google hasn't helped so far. Maybe one of you has the magic answer?

```c++
#include <Wire.h>

#define AD 0x48
#define ID 0x17

byte data1;
byte data2;

uint16_t data_combined;


void setup() {

  analogReference(EXTERNAL);
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(AD); 
 
  Wire.write(ID);   
  Wire.endTransmission(); // I checked the output; is successful

delay(10);

Wire.requestFrom(0x48,2); // Unsure whether to ask for 1 or 2 bytes here; the ChipID, as far as I understand, should only be one byte, but I've been told that I2C transmissions always include at least 2 bytes

data1 = Wire.read(); // so I just save both bytes separately here.
data2 = Wire.read();

data_combined = word(data1,data2);

Serial.print("First byte from Chip ID register: ");
Serial.print(data1,BIN);
Serial.print(" | Second byte from Chip ID register: ");
Serial.print(data2,BIN);
Serial.print(" | Combined to make: ");
Serial.println(data_combined,BIN);
Serial.println("---");

  delay( 200);
}
```

Comment: You might get an answer at [arduino.se].

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7150.pdf) carefully to understand how the chip actually work. You data  "wobbles" is because you are not getting the ChipID as you wish, you are actually reading the CH1 ADC raw data (that is, byte 0 for the status of the chip, byte 1 the higher byte of the 12-bit data on CH1). In order to get the ChipID, you need read 23(0x17) bytes in, the data[0x17] would be the ChipId, I get to know this by reading page 14 of the datasheet and the description of "Read Operation" on page 21.

Comment: If you just want to use the chip and be done with it instead of learning, then I would suggest you use [this library](https://github.com/adrien3d/IO_AD7150).

Comment: Hi hcheung, thank you for your help. I don't understand why the read function starts at the first register. Isn't the purpose of Wire.write() that I do before to set the address pointer to the register I want to read out? Why is that being ignored? Or should I be pointing to the register in a different way? Or does the AD7150 just not work right with Wire? From the data sheet: "The user can also access any unique register (address) on a one-
to-one basis without having to update all the registers. The
address pointer register contents cannot be read." Is this the important point?